# Error: Unable to deactivate keep awake. However, it probably is deactivated already. App created by Expo cli

Tags: expo, react-native

I have created an app by using the following command.

npx create-react-native-app notification

I did not edit the code. Once I launch the app in the Android emulator and If I press the back button and then press the 'Square' button on the Android emulator and try to relaunch the 'notification' app I see the following error message.

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to deactivate keep awake. However, it probably is deactivated already.
promiseMethodWrapper@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2712:45
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:106140:40
deactivateKeepAwake@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:115107:77
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:115095:35
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9616:21

Below is the list of dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~41.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
```

But if I use the react native cli to create the app.
react-native init notification

And perform the same actions then I do not see any warning.

Comment: If you find any solution, please help us by revealing the solution... this issue has been reported by sentry many times but I could not find the bug.